Volumetric Cloud In Eevee not show up
I want to render some volumetric cloud but it not show up
I tried 2 methods in these videos but none working
UPDATE: I tried older version as in video, none of their were working
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlm6w1_ujx0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzJvF1Dx58k



First of all, your Blender version is 4.2.0, the EEVEE render engine has been completely reworked and is now different than in 4.0.0 (the one from the tutorial). Apart from that I would recommend checking the Volumes > Custom Range settings to make sure your cloud within the Start and End range from the camera. However, I was trying to prepare an answer but found this is probably a bug because I found bug reports about volumes being invisible.

And furthermore when trying to set up an answer, I found a different problem on my version 4.2.1 now: the background is black in case there is only a volume object present in the scene (apart from camera and light). Only when adding a mesh object or something that has a surface like a curve with bevel or extruded geometry, or hiding the volume object, the background becomes visible. So maybe this is also a (different?) bug. In my 4.0.1 everything works fine if I set the range correctly like mentioned earlier.
